# Why is scrapy dumping thousands of `ERROR` log messages without any description of the error?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm in the process of writing a `CrawlSpider` that will parse google search results.  The search query changes each time, so the spider must first connect to a database to gather information on the search query it will need to parse.  Here is my anotated `CrawlSpider` class:

```
class GoogleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'googlespider'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com', 'google.ca', 'google.fr']
    logger = log

    _google_query = "http://www.google.{0}/search?q={1}"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GoogleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        dispatcher.connect(self.get_startup_params, signals.spider_opened)

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def get_startup_params(self, spider, **kw):

        # Get the exact requests to issue to google
        exreqs = yield get_exactrequests()

        # Create the google query (i.e. url to scrape) and store associated information
        start_urls = []
        self.item_lookup = {}
        for keyword, exact_request, lang in exreqs['res']:
            url = self.mk_google_query(lang, exact_request)
            start_urls.append(url)
            self.item_lookup[url] = (keyword, exact_request)

        # Assign the google query URLs to `start_urls`
        self.start_urls = tuple(start_urls)

    def mk_google_query(self, lang, search_terms):
        return self._google_query.format(lang, quote(search_terms))

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = Item()
        keyword, exact_request = self.item_lookup[response.request.url]
        item['urls'] = map(lambda r: r.extract(),
                           sel.xpath('//h3[@class="r"]/a/@href'))
        item['keyword'] = keyword
        item['exactrequest'] = exact_request
        return item
```

When I run `scrapy crawl googlespider`, I get a **MASSIVE** log output that looks like this:

> [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR:     2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-]
>   ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100
>   [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17
>   00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR: 2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100 [-] ERROR:
>   2014-02-17 00:24:38+0100

This output goes on for (I would estimate) a good 10,000 lines -- far beyond my terminal's scrollback.

Does anybody know what the issue might be and how I should go about diagnosing/fixing it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you calling `log.start()` somewhere? Also, IIRC, not all signals supports deferreds.

Comment: @Rho,  Yes, this is a good point.  I **am** calling `log.start()` immediately prior to the class definition I posted above.  Should I not do that?  Also, I double-checked and `spider_opened` does indeed support deferreds.

Comment: You should not call log.start() unless you are instantiating the engine by yourself.

Comment: @Rho, the documentation seems to suggest that I *should* be calling `log.start`:  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#scrapy.log.start   What gives?  Can you please point me to the part of the documentation that mentions that I should not do so?

Comment: It seems that comment in the start() method leads to a confusion. The crawler itself starts the logging, see: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/crawler.py#L138 You don't need to call log.start() unless you are not using the main crawler class (that's the default behavior through the scrapy command).

Comment: @Rho, Undersood.  Thanks for the link and for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out @Rho was correct:  the problem stems from the fact that I called `log.start()`.  Removing the call to that function restored sanity.

Answer (score 1):

hard to tell as your log practically say nothing, though the following is recommended:

1. the way you load start_urls seem to be unnecessarily complex, scrapy has a ready made [start_requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) function you can override if your urls generation requires extra work
2. do you inherit `CrawlerSpider` on purpose? as you don't seem to declare any `rule` I assume you should inherit from `Spider` instead

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!  Can I return a `Deferred` from `start_requests`?  I didn't use that because the documentation said nothing about doing so...